# Internal Rules in BNFC for syntax directed translation?

Tags: compiler-construction, bnfc

BNFC allows one to use "internal" rules to aid in syntax directed translation.  The canonical example they give is for type annotation

```
internal VarT . Exp ::= "(" Ident ":" Type ");
```

This gives us a new part of the AST,

```
Exp = ... | VarT Ident Type
```

This works great!  However, what would be really nice is if it were possible to allow an arbitrary type to be put there as a placeholder for later.

```
internal VarT . Exp ::= "(" Ident ":" a ")";
```

And we would generate a parametric datatype

```
Exp a = ... | VarT Ident a
```

Then we could fill this in with a type (for a type checker), or a code segment (for code generation).

Comment: This looks more like a feature request than a question. You can submit it on the [issue tracker for BNFC](https://github.com/bnfc/bnfc/issues?labels=bug&state=open)

Comment: Oh.  It was meant to be a question.  I figured it would be possible, but I just didn't know the syntax.  Do you know that this is not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is currently impossible.